# ReactJS, function for adding/subtracting number doesn't run inside my const

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a game counter in reactJS. I currently have it so you're able to add a player name into an input, and that creates a list below. For every player I need to add a number with + and - buttons.

The functions I have created `minusCount` `plusCount` work perfectly fine when placed inside the `App` function. However, as I need a seperate counter for each player; I am trying to add the function inside `const List` as this will add a new counter to every player added.

The problem I am having is that the `minusCount` and `plusCount` functions are coming back as undefined when placed inside here and the `count` variable is just empty.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import './sass/style.scss';

const initialList = [];

const listReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ITEM':
      return {
        state,
        list: state.list.concat({ number: action.number, name: action.name, id: action.id }),
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
};

export default function App() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(6);

  const [listData, dispatchListData] = React.useReducer(listReducer, {
    list: initialList,
    isShowList: true,
  });
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState('');

  //
  // Handle adding players to the game
  function handleChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleNumber(event) {
    setNumber(event.target.value);
  }
  function handleAdd() {
    dispatchListData({ type: 'ADD_ITEM', name, number, id: uuidv4() });
    setName('');
    setNumber('');
  }

  // THESE FUNCTIONS HAVE ERRORS
  // Handle adding/subtracting lives
  function minusCount() {
    count = count - 1;
    setCount(count);
  }
  function plusCount() {
    count = count + 1;
    setCount(count);
  }

  //
  // Frontend output
  return (
    <section className="player-list">
      <AddItem
        name={name}
        number={number}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onNumber={handleNumber}
        onAdd={handleAdd}
      />
      <div className="player-information">
        <List list={listData.list} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

//
// Handle adding players to the game
const AddItem = ({ number, name, onChange, onNumber, onAdd }) => (
  <form>
    <input type="text" value={name} onChange={onChange} />
    <input type="number" value={number} onChange={onNumber} min="1" max="20" />
    <button type="button" onClick={onAdd}>
      Add
    </button>
  </form>
);

// TRYING TO ADD COUNTER HERE
// Display list of players
const List = ({ list, minusCount, plusCount, count }) => (
  <div className="player-list">
    <div className="player-list-wrapper">
      {list.map((item) => (
        <div className="player">
          <p key={item.id}><b>{item.name}</b><span>{item.number}</span></p>

          // This section doesn't work
          <div className="player-lives">
            <button onClick={minusCount}>-</button>
            <p>{count}</p>
            <button onClick={plusCount}>+</button>
          </div>
          // End This section doesn't work

        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the prop to List component

You have defined your List component with this props

```
const List = ({ list, minusCount, plusCount, count }) => (
```

So you have to pass these props on your Frontend output

```
  // Frontend output
  return (
    <section className="player-list">
      <AddItem
        name={name}
        number={number}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onNumber={handleNumber}
        onAdd={handleAdd}
      />
      <div className="player-information">
        <List list={listData.list}
          minusCount={minusCount}
          plusCount={plusCount}
          count={count}
        />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
```